# Tuning the below query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Can the below query be tuned?  Can i write it without using minus operator

```
( SELECT table_owner || '.' || table_name AS table_name
  FROM all_tab_modifications
  WHERE timestamp >= SYSDATE - 80 AND table_owner IN (
       'AXIOM_DATA',
       'AXIOM_DATA2',
       'AXIOM_META',
       'AXIOM_META2'
  ) AND table_name LIKE 'RPTD_%'
)
MINUS
( SELECT owner || '.' || object_name AS table_name
  FROM dba_objects
  WHERE created >= SYSDATE - 80 AND owner IN (
       'AXIOM_DATA',
       'AXIOM_DATA2',
       'AXIOM_META',
       'AXIOM_META2'
  ) AND object_name LIKE 'RPTD_%' AND object_type = 'TABLE'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try an convert it into a `NOT EXISTS` query. If you do not need the `created >= SYSDATE - 80` , you could query a smaller table  `dba_tables` instead of dba_objects, which means your query could be written as

```
SELECT table_owner || '.' || table_name AS table_name
    FROM all_tab_modifications m
     WHERE timestamp >= SYSDATE - 80 AND table_owner IN (
          'AXIOM_DATA',
          'AXIOM_DATA2',
          'AXIOM_META',
          'AXIOM_META2'
     ) AND table_name LIKE 'RPTD_%' AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM dba_tables t
          WHERE t.owner = m.table_owner AND t.table_name = m.table_name
     );
```

However, if you still want that comparison, the conditions have to be used appropriately in `NOT EXISTS` with the `dba_objects`

```
SELECT table_owner || '.' || table_name AS table_name
     FROM all_tab_modifications m
     WHERE timestamp >= SYSDATE - 80 AND table_owner IN (
          'AXIOM_DATA',
          'AXIOM_DATA2',
          'AXIOM_META',
          'AXIOM_META2'
     ) AND table_name LIKE 'RPTD_%' AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM dba_objects t
          WHERE t.owner = m.table_owner AND t.object_name = m.table_name 
          AND t.object_type ='TABLE'
          AND t.created  >= SYSDATE - 80 
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LEFT JOIN instead of MINUS:

```
SELECT m.table_owner ||'.' ||m.table_name AS table_name 
FROM ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN dba_objects o 
    ON m.table_owner = o.owner 
    AND m.table_name = o.object_name 
    AND o.created >= sysdate -80 
    AND o.object_type = 'TABLE'
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= sysdate -80 
    AND m.table_owner IN ('AXIOM_DATA','AXIOM_DATA2','AXIOM_META','AXIOM_META2') 
    AND m.table_name LIKE 'RPTD_%'
    AND o.table_name IS NULL
```

right part of the join must be null

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Oracle DB to hand to check the indices or Explain plan, but...

```
 SELECT owner || '.' || object_name AS table_name
 FROM dba_objects
 WHERE created >= SYSDATE - 80 AND owner IN (
   'AXIOM_DATA',
   'AXIOM_DATA2',
   'AXIOM_META',
   'AXIOM_META2'
 ) AND object_name LIKE 'RPTD_%' 
 AND object_type != 'TABLE'
```